# Set image size in vosao

Tags: velocity, picasa, vosao

I am trying to show picasa images using Vosao and the velocity engine.  I use:

```
 #set($photos=${service.picasa.findPhotos('Album_Name',50)}) #foreach($photo in $photos)
<div class="slidePage">
  <img class="slideImg" src="$photo.getURL()" />
</div>
#end
```

THis works well but gives me a 512 X 350 image.  The images in picasa are much larger.  If I try and set the size of slideImg any larger, the images look pixilated.  How do I tell picasa what size images to give me.

I tried adding google image api parameters: s=800 to the end but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Add parameter imgmax=max_dimension

so my code above changes to

```
 #set($photos=${service.picasa.findPhotos('Album_Name',50)}) #foreach($photo in $photos)
<div class="slidePage">
  <img class="slideImg" src="$photo.getURL()?imgmax=800" />
</div>
#end
```